# how to send JSON object to kafka from python client

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a simple JSON object like the following

```
d = { 'tag ': 'blah',
  'name' : 'sam',
  'score': 
    {'row1': 100,
      'row2': 200
     }
}
```

The following is my python code which is sending messages to Kafka

```
from kafka import SimpleProducer, KafkaClient
import json 

# To send messages synchronously
kafka = KafkaClient('10.20.30.12:9092')
producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
jd = json.dumps(d)
producer.send_messages(b'message1',jd)
```

I see in the storm logs that the message is being received but its throwing 
Transformation null for tuple { json structure in here } 
not sure what needs to be done in order to fix this ?..

Comment: Please try producer.send_messages(b'message1',d)

Comment: that doesn't work. d will be a dictionary. I need to convert that to string or bytes

Comment: What do you mean by "throwing Transformation null for tuple"?

Comment: Nevermind I solved the issue. I ll soon post the solution.

Comment: @Rahul Can you please Post the solution.... I need to send JSON object to kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is my code for producer to kafka. The only thing i did differently was to use `yaml.safe_load` to load the json content. It returns the contents as strings instead of unicode. The following is the snippet

```
with open('smaller_test_prod.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        d = yaml.safe_load(line)
        jd = json.dumps(d)
        producer.send_messages(b'zeus_metrics',jd)
```

In here every line is a json data stored in a file.

Comment: Why would you use YAML to parse JSON?

Comment: Wish I can downvote this. You can convert the string to utf-8 instead

Answer (score 7):

Kafka expects the values in bytes

```
b`some json message`
```

Here is my simple Kafka producer which sends the message to Kafka server.

```
import json
from bson import json_util

from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

for i in range(10):
    data = { 'tag ': 'blah',
        'name' : 'sam',
        'index' : i,
        'score': 
            {'row1': 100,
             'row2': 200
        }
    }   
    producer.send('orders', json.dumps(data, default=json_util.default).encode('utf-8'))
```

Here json.dumps() convert json into string and encode('utf-8') converts string into byte array.

Comment: Should it not be `producer.send('orders', json.dumps(data, default=json_util.default).encode('utf-8'))`  ("d" should be "data")

Comment: In my case it worked when I added `producer.flush()` in the end of the script